# Report Builder cascading parameter not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have these dataset (NOTE the data is from power bi service not SQL. I am using sql for example, if it were from SQL I will have been able to do it)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Calendar') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Calendar
create table #Calendar (Day_of_Week varchar(20), Dates Date)
Insert into #Calendar values
('Monday','2023-11-20'),('Tuesday','2023-11-21'),('Wednesday','2023-11-22'),
('Thursday','2023-11-23'),('Friday','2023-11-24'),('Saturday','2023-11-25'),
('Sunday','2023-11-26')
select * from #Calendar
```

I created two Parameters
[image]

For day_of_week parameter I want to be able to filter for day of week for Sunday and Thursday Only. If I chose Sundy the 2nd parameter Dates should show Sunday date 26/11/2023 and if I chose Thursday the dates parameter you display 23/11/2023.
What I did is to link the two parameters
For day_of_week parameter
Defaulted Sunday

[image]

[image]

I filtered Dates parameter by the day_of-week parameter

[image]

I link the Show dataset back to Dates parameter
[image]

When i run the report

[image]

It only shows sunday Date even whe i change the day to Thursday. the date wont change
My expected output is
[image]